# How to send and receive domain objects with rabbitMQ plugin and grails

Tags: grails, groovy, rabbitmq, messaging

I've went over the excellent documentation for the rabbitMQ plugin. However, I am still confused about a few things.

**Scenario**

My application will take a file upload from the user, do various things to the file and accordingly set certain properties on the domain object. Some of this work can be labor intensive so I am using a queue. I envision requests being queued and the consumer picking up the requests from the queue and consuming them.

**Questions**

I want to store a domain object in the queue. I do this by: `rabbitSend 'myqueue', colorObj`. `colorObj`is an object of domain class `Color`
However, in the `ColorService` `handleMessage(...)` When I fetch the item from the queue, the item is not of type `Color`. Please note that on the rabbitMQ dashboard I can see the items being inserted in the queue, so my queue initiation in `config.groovy` is fine (I am using `amq.direct`)

- How can I send and fetch a domain object from the queue?
- From the behavior I've seen thus far, the `handleMessage` does not need to be instantiated. Even if I don't call the `ColorService` it still executes `handleMessage` by itself. Is that a normal behavior?

Below is the code:

*controller*

```
Color colorObj = colorService.newRequest(params, request.getFile('color.filename')
if (colorObj.validate)
  rabbitSend 'myqueue', colorObj
...
```

*service*

```
class ColorService {
  static rabbitQueue = 'myqueue'

  void handleMessage(message) {
    println "came in message: " + message instanceof Color //this prints false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it shows [in the documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-rabbitmq/docs/manual/ref/All%20Classes/rabbitSend.html), you can either send a `String` or a `Map`

Why not send the `id` of your domain object:

```
rabbitSend 'myqueue', colorObj.id
```

Then, load it back in when the message is processed:

```
void handleMessage(message) {
    println "Got ${Color.get( message )}"
}
```

Or, if you don't need the domain object until the message is processed, send a map of all the required data, and have the service create the domain object after it is processed successfully?

Answer (score 2):

As Tim says, if you can get by with just passing the domain instance ID that is simplest. You do need to be careful of changes to the domain instance while the message is in transit though.

Alternatively, if it's the data you're interested in, I prefer to serialise the objects as JSON using something like

```
rabbitSend 'myqueue', (colorObj as JSON).toString()
```

Of course, now your listener is receiving a string, so you'll have to convert it back:

```
void handleMessage(String message) {
    def color = new Color(JSON.parse(message))
    println "came in message: " + color instanceof Color
}
```

There is a little bit of discussion around this on the [GPRABBITMQ-15 issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRABBITMQ-15).

Comment: Great, I will try the ID as that is the simplest method. Also, am I clear in my understanding that the `handleMessage` in the service class does not need to be instantiated? behavior I'm seeing is that soon as I enqueue something, the service handlemessage gets to work without me even instantiating the service

Comment: Correct, the plugin automatically instantiates `ColorService` and attaches it to a message listener container because of the `static rabbitQueue` property.